# How to set the View at Word startup using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to set the `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View` properties for the blank document MS Word displays on startup. At the Application.Initialise event there is no active document, and the Document_New event doesn't occur. Does anyone know how to address that first document or otherwise get a hold on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using the DocumentChange event. You will need to set a flag to indicate that you are at startup before you initialise your event handler so that it only responds the once.

```
Private Sub AppWord_DocumentChange()
    If Documents.Count > 0 Then
        If InStartup Then
            InStartup = False
            If Left(ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate, 10) = "Normal.dot" Then
                ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View = wdNormalView
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

My guess is that you have added your code into Normal.dotm. If that is the case it would explain why you can't trap the events at startup.

The default blank document that Word creates is based on Normal.dotm. As a result any code it contains only gets loaded **after** that document has been created, ergo after the events have fired. This makes Normal.dotm a very poor host for an event handler. Personally I avoid using Normal.dotm for anything other than sketching out code for answers to questions!

A better home for code in Word is its equivalent of the add-ins that can be created for Excel and PowerPoint, a template that is loaded at startup. This is placed in the folder defined in Word as the Startup folder (File | Options | Advanced | General | File Locations). By default it is %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP for Windows. Place the template containing your code in that folder and it will be loaded **before** the blank document gets created and will enable you to respond to the events.

[image]

Comment: The event also doesn't occur on startup. However, it occurs on exit. Therefore I can set the view at that time and Word will remember the setting for its next use. :-)

Comment: That's odd because that event fires for me in both Word 2010 and Word 2016, in both instances running the code from a Startup template.

Comment: Apologies if the information in my edited answer is already familiar to you.

Comment: My turn to apologise. It was my method of testing that produced the wrong result. The event does fire as promised. My bad. I'm sorry but grateful for your persistence.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I implemented.

```
Private Sub App_DocumentChange()
    ' 27 May 2017

    Static Done As Boolean

    If Not Done Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If ActiveDocument.Path = "" Then SetView ActiveDocument
        Done = True
    End If
End Sub
```